# What does it mean when a company issues options that would not expire until 3 years later?

Tags: stock-markets

I saw people discussing a stock that just issued options expired 3 years later.

They said that would be an indication the stock would boost.

Why does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically a company issues options on itself in order to serve as an employee incentive.  For a very low cost, they can entice employees to work long hours at below market pay in order to participate in the rise of the company's value.  Typically these options expire after ten years, not three.

An exchange may issue options on a security for one reason only:  they can sell them.

Comment: so the options i saw in my broker is not issued by company, but exchange (NYSE or Nasdaq)?

Comment: @AGamePlayer Yes - a company does not typically get involved in options on its own shares except in offering them to employees as an incentive, as Pete mentioned.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon thanks! Is there a way to know more about the issue rules? Like a link from nyse or nasdaq. Thanks!